# why unselection is not working for multiple items with selectable and draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable

i  want my `unselection`  of list items work as smooth as `.selectable()` without `.draggable()`

**My expectation is something like below `gif` with `selectable` and `draggable` combined:**

[image]

**here above code without `draggable`:**

```js
   $("#selectable").selectable();
```

```css
  #feedback {
      font-size: 1.4em;
  }
  #selectable .ui-selecting {
      background: #FECA40;
  }
  #selectable .ui-selected {
      background: #F39814;
      color: white;
  }
  #selectable {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 60%;
  }
  #selectable li {
      margin: 3px;
      padding: 0.4em;
      font-size: 1.4em;
      height: 18px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

**Question:**  the below combined  `selectable` and `draggable` **selection** and **unselection** is not working as above code with only `selectable`

**here is what i have tried:**

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
           start: function (event, ui) {
                 /* $('.ui-widget-content').draggable('destroy') */;
             },
       stop: function(event,ui){
           $('.ui-widget-content').draggable({
               drag: function(event,ui){
                  console.log('dragging....');
                  $('#multiple_selected_rows').remove();
                  var elem = document.createElement("div");
                  elem.id = "multiple_selected_rows";
                  elem.innerText = $('li.ui-selected').length+" items";
                  document.body.appendChild(elem);
                  
                   $("#multiple_selected_rows").css({ 'top': event.clientY + 10, 'left': event.clientX + 10 });
               }
           });
           $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
       }
    });
    
    $('#droppable').droppable({
        accept: '.ui-widget-content',
        greedy: true,
        drop: function (event, ui) {
           $('#multiple_selected_rows').remove();
        }   
    });
 });
```

```css
#feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
  #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
  #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; /*width: 60%;*/ padding:22px; border: solid 1px #0973c7;}
  #selectable li { margin: 8px; padding:10px; border:solid 1px #CCC;}
  .ui-selectable-helper { position: absolute; z-index: 100; border:1px dotted black; } 

#main-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

div#main-container .demo {
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 7px;
}

div#main-container #droppable {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#multiple_selected_rows{
   position:absolute;
   width: 90px;
   height:40px;
   background:red;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id="main-container">
     <div class="demo">
        <ol id="selectable">
          <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
          <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
          <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
          <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
          <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
          <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
          <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div id="droppable">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: Have you tried adding transition along with background, this might give a better result

Comment: I would suggest adding a draggable handle to the right or left of the items, this way you only drag when mousing on the handles.

Comment: @Souleste I agree. This is the only way to keep the method of selecting shown in the example gif while still allowing the items to be dragged.  See the last part of my answer for a working example.

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** The way you are drag selecting multiple items and then immediately selecting only a single item by clicking on it (as shown in the gif) will not be possible if you are going to drag the selected items to another box. You can either drag a selection with `selectable()`, or drag, i.e. move, your selected items with `draggable()`, not both.

---

Your `selectable()` and `draggable()` methods are competing with one another for the same mouse events.  So instead of setting them up on page load, try this:

In the `selectable()` `stop` callback, wrap the selected elements in a div:

```
$('.ui-selected').wrapAll('<div id="dragSet"></div>');
```

Then call `draggable()` on `#dragSet`. Now this call will take precedence over the `selectable()` mouse events for the selected items.

In the `draggable()` `stop` callback, append the selected items to `#droppable` and remove their `.ui-selected` class.

```
$('#droppable').append( $('#dragSet') );
$('#dragSet').contents().unwrap();
$('#droppable li').removeClass('ui-selected');
```

Finally, add some logic to the `selectable()` `start` callback to prevent double wrapping your selection.

```
if ( $('#dragSet').children().length > 0 ) $('#dragSet').contents().unwrap();
else $('#dragSet').remove();
```

See working example below:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#selectable").selectable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
      if ($('#dragSet').children().length > 0) $('#dragSet').contents().unwrap();
      else $('#dragSet').remove();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $('.ui-selected').wrapAll('<div id="dragSet"></div>');
      $('#dragSet').draggable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
          $('#droppable').append($('#dragSet'));
          $('#dragSet').contents().unwrap();
          $('#droppable li').removeClass('ui-selected');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}

#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}

#selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*width: 60%;*/
  padding: 22px;
  border: solid 1px #0973c7;
}

#selectable li {
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
}

.ui-selectable-helper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

#main-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div#main-container .demo {
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

div#main-container #droppable {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#multiple_selected_rows {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#droppable li.ui-widget-content {
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  color: white;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id="main-container">
  <div class="demo">
    <ol id="selectable">
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div id="droppable">

  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Bonus:

To drag back and forth, repeat the same JS and swap `#selectable` with `#droppable`.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#selectable").selectable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
      if ($('#dragSet').children().length > 0) $('#dragSet').contents().unwrap();
      else $('#dragSet').remove();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $('.ui-selected').wrapAll('<div id="dragSet"></div>');
      $('#dragSet').draggable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
          $('#droppable').append($('#dragSet'));
          $('#dragSet').contents().unwrap();
          $('#droppable li').removeClass('ui-selected');
        }
      });
    }
  });

  $("#droppable").selectable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
      if ($('#dragSet').children().length > 0) $('#dragSet').contents().unwrap();
      else $('#dragSet').remove();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $('.ui-selected').wrapAll('<div id="dragSet"></div>');
      $('#dragSet').draggable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
          $('#selectable').append($('#dragSet'));
          $('#dragSet').contents().unwrap();
          $('#selectable li').removeClass('ui-selected');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

#selectable .ui-selecting,
#droppable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}

#selectable .ui-selected,
#droppable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}

#selectable,
#droppable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 22px;
  border: solid 1px #0973c7;
}

#selectable li,
#droppable li {
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
}

.ui-selectable-helper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

#main-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div#main-container .demo {
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

div#main-container #droppable {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id="main-container">
  <div class="demo">
    <ol id="selectable">
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div id="droppable">

  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Selectable and Draggable with selection as shown in the gif:

Normally, you would need to click on the selected items in order to drag them. But since you want to be able to click on them to make a new selection, you'll need to add another element as a handle to drag them by.

```js
$(function() {
  $( "#selectable" ).selectable({      
    start: function (event, ui) {
        if ( $('#dragSet').children().length > 0 ) {
          $('#dragHandle').remove();
          $('#dragSet').contents().unwrap();
        }
        else $('#dragSet').remove();        
    },
    stop: function(event,ui){        
      $('.ui-selected').wrapAll('<div id="dragSet"></div>');
      $('#dragSet').append('<div id="dragHandle">Drag Me</div>');
      $('#dragHandle').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $('#dragSet').draggable({
          stop: function(event, ui){            
            $('#droppable').append( $('#dragSet') );
            $('#dragHandle').remove();
            $('#dragSet').contents().unwrap();
            $('#droppable li').removeClass('ui-selected');          
          }
        });
      }).on('mouseleave', function() {
        $('#dragSet').draggable('destroy');
      }); 
    }
  });

  $( "#droppable" ).selectable({      
    start: function (event, ui) {
        if ( $('#dragSet').children().length > 0 ) {
          $('#dragHandle').remove();
          $('#dragSet').contents().unwrap();          
        }
        else $('#dragSet').remove();        
    },
    stop: function(event,ui){        
      $('.ui-selected').wrapAll('<div id="dragSet"></div>');
      $('#dragSet').append('<div id="dragHandle">Drag Me</div>');
      $('#dragHandle').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $('#dragSet').draggable({
          stop: function(event, ui){            
            $('#selectable').append( $('#dragSet') );
            $('#dragHandle').remove();
            $('#dragSet').contents().unwrap();
            $('#selectable li').removeClass('ui-selected');          
          }
        });
      }).on('mouseleave', function() {
        $('#dragSet').draggable('destroy');
      });
    }
  });
 });
```

```css
#feedback { 
  font-size: 1.4em; 
}

#selectable .ui-selecting,
#droppable .ui-selecting { 
  background: #FECA40; 
}

#selectable .ui-selected,
#droppable .ui-selected { 
  background: #F39814; 
  color: white; 
}

#selectable, 
#droppable { 
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  padding:22px; 
  border: solid 1px #0973c7;
}

#selectable li,
#droppable li { 
  margin: 8px; 
  padding:10px; 
  border:solid 1px #CCC;
}

.ui-selectable-helper { 
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 100; 
  border:1px dotted black; 
} 

#main-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div#main-container .demo {
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

div#main-container #droppable {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#dragSet {
  position: relative;
}

#dragHandle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 12px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id="main-container">
  <div class="demo">
    <ol id="selectable">
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div id="droppable">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's nice but `un-selection` is not happening as asked in a gif image in question

Comment: my main concern is selection and un-selection as per gif

Comment: @EaBengaluru How do you expect to drag the items to your #droppable box if clicking on them deselects the group? Your question is how to combine `selectable()` and `draggable()`. They both require a click. If you want to select the same way as shown in the gif, you'll have to give up on the `draggable()` and create a button that transfers the selection to the other box.

Comment: I'm least bothered about `drag` functionality, that I will handle somehow. But I don't want to remove `draggable`. I'm most bothered on selection,unselection right now